# How to create interactive dvds for tv

Tags: flash, dvd, television

I have created an app using flash. I want to make a dvd of this app with all the button functionality and play it on tv. How do i provide the navigation functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DVD authoring tool like Nero (there are several others, just search for it on google)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **Director**, it is an Adobe program for creating interactive DVDs. Never tried it but it has many tutorials and online courses on the web.